# How many Zombies are there in "Black Tide Rising"?

Tags: black-tide-rising

In the *Black Tide Rising* series written by John Ringo, we have a zombie apocalypse.

We know the uninfected survivors amount to 1%. Is there a way to find out what the percentage of the zombies and what percentage of the dead is? If you have read the books, you should know that the zombies are not the living dead.

The best information that could be used as a source are:

At the time of the clearing of the Royal Netherlands Liner P/V Saga of Amsterdam:

- 9 rounds per infected (supposedly in Iraq 6 000 rounds per stepped on kill, and 60 000 in the Korean War)

Cleaning of San Sebastian de la Gomera, Gomera, Canary Islands, Spain:

- Population ~8 000 (pre-Plague)
- Rounds used: 35 000 rounds of .50 + 9 000 rounds of 7.62 and 6 000 of 5.56
- described as 1/6 of the amount of ammo in terms of similar conditions in Iraq

Does this somehow help more?

Comment: ~99%? Or is this a trick question?

Comment: I think OP means the breakdown of the other 99% into % 'zombie' and % who are just plain dead. Did the plague kill some people as well as turn people?

Comment: @tojo: You are quite right. Every sickness can be lethal, but there are many other ways a person could have died: lack of water and food (even if not infected), euthanasia, in-fighting, accidents, in-fighting, natural causes,...

Comment: Paul George > John Ringo.

Answer (score 1):

Doctor Curry's report to the Bank of the Americas executive meeting ("Under a Graveyard Sky"):

- 5% mortality rate from flu stage
- 20% mortality from the neurological stage

As for the rest - impossible to say, as the survivability ratio will be a function of time and conditions. In other words: the later after the plague start, there will be more dead and less survivors, as well as access to "drinking" water means zombies surviving in large numbers.

Then there's cannibalism - like the

> boat where father ate his spouse and kids. And all kinds and instances of snuff sex and turf wars, where youngsters and females usually lose.

So this is extremely hard to say how many zombies we have. I would say impossible and I think the books never say even the estimation of alive zombies, let alone some proportion. I think it's a moot question - you can't save them, only way is to eliminate them. Even the estimates for required manpower and ammunition for clearance are calculated based on deck/land area cleared to date, not numbers killed.

Also, it's worth noticing that there is a difference between "not infected" and "uninfected" survivors. Former are ones who avoided the plague whole, latter are the ones not contracting neurological sickness (after being exposed to plague). And while normally the former would be insignificant number, in the "Zombie Apocalypse" their number is statistically very significant.

Answer (score 0):

It estimates 10% total survival rate of humanity and 1% uninfection rate, which implies 9% of the world population persist as zeds.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When you say "it estimates," what is "it?"  Can you add the exact quote from the text for that number?